# ActionView::MissingTemplate in Posts#show (Issues with Partials)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have searched around and have found similar errors to the one I'm facing. However, it seems like my error is the same but with different circumstances slightly different.

I'm attempting to navigate to localhost:3000/posts/2 the error says
`ActionView::MissingTemplate in Posts#show`
Here is the full error screenshot http://screencast.com/t/alwZHL9bkcKH

On my post_controller.rb I have this

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I have a partials folder /views/categories with _categories.html.erb inside.

```
<span class="badge"><%= category.name %></span>
```

if I exclude my categories partial _categories.html.erb and insert the following into show.html.erb

```
<% @post.categories.each do |category| %>
  <span class="badge"><%= category.name %></span>
<% end %>
```

It works perfectly.

what is the issue causing this partial issue? Why can't it be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the partial file should be [singular](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

```
_category.html.erb
```

It says so even quite plainly in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is looking for a file named `_category...` in `views/categories/`. Change the partial's filename to `_category.html.erb`